# How can I resize an iframe with an external source and offset the contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, iframe

How can I:

1. Wait for an external iFrame to load
2. Resize externally sourced iFrame (ex: 100px x 40px)
3. Offset externally sourced iFrame (ex: 25px x 50px)

Sample code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Here's Google's Logo Today:</p>
    <iframe id="google_logo" src="http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow"></iframe>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know you can't get contents of external iFrame, but what about resizing and offsetting?

I also know my example is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fire an event when an external iframe has fully loaded, the rest is possible though.

Wrap the frame in a div

```
<div id="frame_wrapper">
  <iframe id="google_logo" src="http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow"></iframe>
</div>
```

Add the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#frame_wrapper").addClass("iframe_shift");
});
```

Add the following CSS

```
#google_logo { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.iframe_shift { width:100px; height: 45px; position: relative; top: 25px; left: 45px;  }​
```